# Newtonsoft.Json library and serializing .NET decimal type

Tags: c#, json, serialization, decimal, json.net

I've some .NET type with property of type `Decimal`

The value of this property before serializing is 4.99

(I use Newtonsoft.Json library for serialization purposes)

But when it is serialized it is represented as 4.9900

Is there any way to avoid such behavior?
Thanks

Comment: The documentation [here](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm) shows that the value should be correctly converted. Are you sure it's correctly defined? Post your code so that we can analyze it.

Comment: Thanks for replies. It is defined correctly. I think go for creating custom type converter as James shares. Thanks guys!.